# Large consumption of resources when stopping Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, memory, httpd, crash

During the stop of the apache service, the httpd -prefork processes take 100% load on all cores and take up all available memory, as a result of which the oom killer is triggered.

Stop command:
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/start_apache2 -DSYSTEMD -DFOREGROUND -k graceful-stop

Why is this happening and how can these loads be reduced?
This happens every night at logrotate.

Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Linux/SUSE)